# MongoDB $gte and $lte not getting desired results

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve data within a given time frame.
with the following Query

```
db.readings.find({TS:{"$gte":"16/12/18 00:00:00","$lte":"17/12/18 24:00:00"}});
```

and for some reason its not returning my desired data.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4d31843fa3b6103e63d293"), "IMEI" : NumberLong("353438065610052"), "TS" : "17/07/18 00:00:00", "P" : "MK6E_NORECO2-DTB-Delta", "A" : 1, "ST" : 0, "V1" : 31290, "V2" : 19678, "V3" : 62568, "V4" : 19289, "V5" : 42839, "V6" : 19694, "V7" : 12496, "V8" : 17825, "status" : "DONE" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4d318f3fa3b666736c767d"), "IMEI" : NumberLong("353438065610052"), "TS" : "17/07/18 00:00:00", "P" : "MK6E_NORECO2-DTB-Delta", "A" : 1, "ST" : 8, "V1" : 13357, "V2" : 17537, "V3" : 44380, "V4" : 17860, "V5" : 43819, "V6" : 17266, "V7" : 42630, "V8" : 17266, "V9" : 0, "V10" : 0, "V11" : 45080, "V12" : 16819, "V13" : 44458, "V14" : 16819, "V15" : 0, "V16" : 0, "V17" : 53075, "V18" : 48977, "V19" : 31968, "V20" : 17007, "status" : "DONE" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4d31953fa3b667ee516878"), "IMEI" : NumberLong("353438063633361"), "TS" : "17/07/18 00:00:00", "P" : "Integra_RFM Main Power Supply", "A" : 1, "ST" : 0, "V1" : 16880, "V2" : 0, "V3" : 16880, "V4" : 0, "V5" : 16256, "V6" : 0, "V7" : 18323, "V8" : 41728, "V9" : 17224, "V10" : 0, "V11" : 16904, "V12" : 0, "V13" : 16672, "V14" : 0, "V15" : 0, "V16" : 0, "V17" : 0, "V18" : 0, "V19" : 16576, "V20" : 0, "status" : "DONE" }
```

but if i adjust the query with this values

```
 db.readings.find({TS:{"$gte":"16/12/18 00:00:00","$lte":"16/12/18 24:00:00"}});
```

it give me my desired result .

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c17023d3fa3b60d8f136b47"), "IMEI" : NumberLong("353438063612373"), "TS" : "16/12/18 01:03:00", "P" : "MK6N", "A" : 10, "ST" : 1536, "V1" : 18492, "V2" : 8157, "status" : "INITIAL_INSERT" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c17023d3fa3b60d8f136b47"), "IMEI" : NumberLong("353438063612373"), "TS" : "16/12/18 01:03:00", "P" : "MK6N", "A" : 10, "ST" : 1536, "V1" : 18492, "V2" : 8157, "status" : "INITIAL_INSERT" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c1702b33fa3b60d99474007"), "IMEI" : NumberLong("353438063612373"), "TS" : "16/12/18 01:03:00", "P" : "MK6N", "A" : 10, "ST" : 1536, "V1" : 18492, "V2" : 8157, "status" : "INITIAL_INSERT" }
```

After Checking the table I found that "TS" is actually a string.

Answer (score 2):

Might it be that `24:00:00` could cause the problem? IMO it should be `00:00:00` or `24:00:00`, not both.
Your `17/12/18 24:00:00` would then be `18/12/18 00:00:00` or `17/12/18 23:59:59`

or

you could try `db.readings.find({TS:{"$gte":new Date("16/12/18 00:00:00"),"$lte":new Date("17/12/18 23:59:59")}});`

Comment: I'm currently doing it on ruby so im not sure how to use 'new Date("17/12/18 23:59:59")'. but i did tried changing 24:00:00 to 23:59:59 but it has given me the same results